# .net core with Docker Https wrong redirect when different port mapping

Tags: c#, docker, ssl, https, .net-core

I create a .net core webapi project with ssl.

```
.ConfigureKestrel((hostingContext, options) =>
                        {
                            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                            if (env.IsProduction())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("In Production");
                                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 80);
                                options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
                                {
                                    listenOptions.UseHttps("./cert.pfx", "password");
                                });
                            }
                        });
```

And run in docker:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 core
```

It works great!. Https redirect correct 80->443

However, when i change the port mapping:

```
docker run -p 5000:80 -p 5001:443 core
```

Https redirect wrong 5000 -> 443, not 5001, so it does't work as no port 443 expose in host, it is only in docker container.

`5000(host)->80(docker)--redirect-> 443(host) -X-> 443(docker)`

Then, i change AddHttpsRedirection in Startup.cs with below

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
            {
                options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status308PermanentRedirect;
                options.HttpsPort = 5001;
            });
```

It redirect correct now, 5000 -> 5001, i guess it is because, the redirect is :

`5000(host)->80(docker)--redirect->5001(host)->443(docker)`

Is this normal behavior? or Any config is wrong/missing with docker?

I expect when i change mapping `-p 5000:80 -p 5001:443`,
is 5000->5001 not 5000->443

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have already found the cause, not sure, but this is normal behavior.

> I expect when i change mapping -p 5000:80 -p 5001:443, is 5000->5001 not 5000->443

When you visit `5000(host port)`, docker will use iptables to route the traffic to `80(container port)`, as redirection was designed in your container's `80 service`, so the browser receive the indication to redirect to `443(host port)`.

NOTE: here, the redirect in fact happens on client side(browser or others), so the client had to again connect to host server's `443 port`, then you failure.

But if you change your code in container, then the indication sent to client will be `Hi, client, redirect to 5001 port please`, then it will work.

And some additional I guess you already know:

> -p port1:port2

The first port means host's port, and the second port means container's port, it means all traffic to host's port1 will route to container's port2.

**Update for .Net Core with docker**

for .net core with docker config as below can handle this case:

```
docker run
-p 5000:80 \
-p 5001:443 \
-e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=5001 \
-e ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+ \
-e Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/path/to/certificate.pfx \
-e Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=password
```

Comment: vote for deeper explain the redirect concept, and edit for adding my final solution. Reference :  http://parsstudent.com/asp-net-core-2-1-application-in-docker-with-https-enabled/